# Python Fabric + multiple host configuration in database

Tags: python, database, django, deployment, fabric

I'm working on Django application assisting deployment processes of Python applications using Fabric.

I know moderately both Fabric and Django, but I'm not sure how can/should I use them in order to be able to run deployment and other tasks on servers than configuration is stored in the database.

The thing is, I have all needed server credentials stored in the database and want to be able to use them instead of declaring particular hosts in fabfile.py (or maybe somehow parameterizing them, to call ie. sth like "fab server1_from_database deploy"). I need to be able to add/edit/delete hosts from the Django application itself, without editing fabfile.py.

Is it somehow possible to achieve this?

Thank you for any help, I'm totally stuck here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not hard to do. In your fabfile, initialize the `env` object with credentials from the database:

```
from fabric.api import *

credentials = load_credentials_from_your_db()
for (hostname, username, password) in credentials:
    host_string = username + '@' + hostname
    env.hosts.append(host_string)
    env.passwords[host_string] = password
```

It's untested, but the docs say it should work.